# Issue trying to run Flutter app built by another developer

Tags: android, flutter

I keep getting this same message and I have no idea how to fix this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM M315F in debug mode...
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_custom_dialog'.
    > Could not load compiled classes for build file 'E:\SDK\Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_custom_dialog-1.2.0\android\build.gradle' from cache.
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 3s
    Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This path is basically where my Flutter SDK is stored `'E:\SDK\Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_custom_dialog-1.2.0\android\build.gradle'`

P.S: The app runs when Chrome is chosen as the option for debugging but not on the phone or emulator. Any clue as to why that is the case?

Comment: Which version of flutter are you using and  on which channel i.e. dev or stable ?

Comment: Change the version of gradle

Comment: @HardikMehta I'm currently using 2.5.3 and I'm assuming I'm on the stable channel as there's a star next to it when I check using flutter channel

Comment: can you check on latest flutter version as current on stable is 2.8.1

Comment: @HardikMehta I think the issue lies with the flutter_custom_dialog package imported from pud.dev. Do you think updating the flutter version could resolve this?

Comment: then you can do one thing : flutter clean , flutter pub get and then try to run again before upgrade to latest one

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle, change gradle version. Check by both upgrading and downgrading until it is compatible with your package

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**try it with 3.5.0**